# How to fix embarcadero link error : [ilink32 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'RTL.BPI'

Tags: c++, c++builder

When compiling my project on the c++ builder the project doesn't compile successfully, I get the following error [ilink32 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'RTL.BPI' which I've been trying to fix.

Answer (score 2):

Confirm your PC OS as to whether you're operating on 32 bit or 64 bit, then on the compiler, to your right click on target platforms, select add platform, add the version matching your os version. if you're on 32bit then add 32bit and select 32bit, If you're 64bit then add and select 64bit.

If you do not have a platform matching your OS version then install the C++ Builder version matching your OS version.

Then compile your project again, it should not give you the : [ilink32 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'RTL.BPI' compile error afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you still have the problem but it happened with me just now. I fixed in a simple way. In my case the file rtl.bpi exists in the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\lib\win32\release". I made a copy of this file in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\lib\win32\debug". After doing this, I tried to compile again but the system had the same problems with other four files. I did the same procedures. I copied this other files from "release" to "debug". After this my problem was solved. In my case the other files were: fxm.bpi, memmgr.lib and sysinit.obj.

Comment: I had the same problem and this fixed it for me. Thanks mate.